# Selenium - Iterating through groups of elements - Python

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to iterate over a number of elements returned by matching class names, which I have stored in an array `users`. The `print(len(users))` outputs as 12, which is accurately correct as to how many returned there should be. This is my code:

```
def follow():
    time.sleep(2)
    # iterate here
    users = []
    users = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('wo9IH')
    print(len(users))
    for user in users:
        user_button = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('li.wo9IH div.Pkbci').click()
        #user_button = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="Pkbci"]/button').click()
```

However currently, only index [0] is being `.click()`'d and the program is terminating after this first click. What would be the problem as to why the index being iterated isn't incrementing?

**resource:** [image](http://image.ibb.co/jdBU7f/unknown.png) - red shows what's being iterated through and blue is each button being .click()'d

Comment: Class `wo9IH` and `Pkbci` looks dynamic. Consider other attributes. Update the question with the relevant html and error stack trace (if any).

Comment: https://image.ibb.co/jdBU7f/unknown.png - red shows what's being iterated through and blue is each button being `.click()`'d

Comment: Instead of providing updates through comments, update the main question for further analysis.

Comment: Do you get any error? does the button html changes after the click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,
You can directly make array of `buttons` rather than `li` array,
Go click all buttons contains text as `Follow`,
simple,

```
browser.maximize_window()
users = []
    users = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('*//button[text()='Follow']')
print(len(users))  # check it must be 12

for user in users:
        browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", user)
        # user.click()  Go click all buttons
```

Comment: I'm getting `TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not iterable` ?

Comment: my bad try `find_elements_by_xpath()` srry @CeraMix

Comment: Message: unknown error: Element `<button class="oW_lN oF4XW sqdOP yWX7d       " type="button">...</button>` is not clickable at point (877, 341). Other element would receive the click: `<div class="_914pk _ETeu">...</div>`

Comment: Hi @CeraMix  you are gettting `len(users)` as `12` Right ?

Answer (score 0):

Find all your css_selector elements as a list and then iterate that list to perform .click()

```
yourList = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('w0o9IH div.Pkbci')
```

Answer (score 0):

`users = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('wo9IH')` returns a list of `selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement` instances that can also be transversed.

In your implementation of the iteration, the above fact about the items in the list is overlooked and the entire page is search by transversing the page source from the `WebDriver` instance (*i.e.* `browser.find_element_by_css_selector`).

Here is how to go about getting the button in the matched `WebElement`s:

```
for user_web_element in users:
    # The next line given that there is only a single <button> 
    # in the screenshot for the matched WebElements.
    user_button = user_web_element.find_element_by_tag_name('button')
    user_button.click()
```